# Blazor bind table to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've a dynamic table and wanting to update the s from code, tried this way but getting error:

`@bind is not a valid attribute name`

```
@foreach (var item in Products)
{
    <tr>
      <td @bind="@(item.Price)">@(item.Price)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

How should I bind data tags to list items properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@foreach (var item in Products)
{
    <tr @key=item>
      <td><InputText @bind=item.Price/></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@foreach (var item in Products)
{
    <tr>
      <td>@item.Price</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

InputText not working: InputText requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext.

also `<td @bind="item.Price">` didn't work too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you have a additional information about your problem, you can edit your post and add it . You must not add it like as additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@key` for the render engine to diff the updates.

```
@foreach (var item in Products)
{
    <tr @key=item>
      <td>@item.Price</td>
    </tr>
}
```