# Best way to avoid blocking Razor pages on load

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am writing a Blazor application by creating some Razor pages, one of which is displaying a list of Drugs when the user navigates to it. The database in hosted on SQL Server and is quite big taking a time to load the first time. What's the best way to navigate there and avoid blocking the interface.

I believe I should modify something there but what?

```
  protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       drugs = DrugService.GetDrugs();  //a really long task taking at least 5 seconds.
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
```

Comment: I think u have a bad approach by loading all Drugs on Init. Why do u need them all 100000 records? Load only what is needed or use pagination or other techniques.

Comment: @DA Please open to suggestions.

Comment: I don't know your UI and your needs but u can use a grid with pagination for example, or search on demand. On the server side u can use a Redis server for a fast load or another caching approach. So depends a lot on what u have to accomplish.

Comment: My UI is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/67334388/8650243

Comment: Use a UI with infinite scroll if you want to show them all like this https://www.meziantou.net/infinite-scrolling-in-blazor.htm

Comment: Yes, but what should I change in `OnInitializedAsync` since there is nothing there besides the table.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Blazor virtualization. It loads a limited amount of data per scroll.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a data pipeline that only gets the data you want.  At the moment you're getting an unconstrained list, which could be huge.

Here's some demo code based on the `FetchData` page using the `Virtualize` component that fetches data in chunks.

My List Handler that does the real work.  It takes a `ItemsProviderRequest` that defines the page/chunk of data you want to retrieve, and returns an `ItemsProviderResult` containing the data set requested and the total count available to query.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SO76117538.Data;

public class WeatherForecastListHandler
{
    private readonly WeatherForecastProvider _weatherForecastProvider;

    public WeatherForecastListHandler(WeatherForecastProvider weatherForecastProvider)
        => _weatherForecastProvider = weatherForecastProvider;

    public async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<WeatherForecast>> ExecuteAsync(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        // normally get DbContext
        // var query = _dbContext.WeatherForecasts;

        // Get the IEnumerable/IQueryable object
        var query = await _weatherForecastProvider.GetForecastAsync();

        var count = query is IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast>
            ? await query.CountAsync()
            : query.Count();

        query = query
            .Skip(request.StartIndex)
            .Take(request.Count);

        // Materialize as a list from the DbContext from the data store
        var list = query is IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast>
            ? await query.ToListAsync()
            : query.ToList();

        // return as an enumerable to make it readonly
        return new ItemsProviderResult<WeatherForecast>(list.AsEnumerable(), count);
    }
}
```

The `WeatherForecastService` is the data presentation layer for the UI.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization;

namespace SO76117538.Data;

public class WeatherForecastService
{
    private readonly WeatherForecastListHandler _weatherForecastListHandler;

    public WeatherForecastService(WeatherForecastListHandler weatherForecastListHandler)
        => _weatherForecastListHandler = weatherForecastListHandler;

    public ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastsAsync(ItemsProviderRequest request)
        => _weatherForecastListHandler.ExecuteAsync(request);
}
```

And the modified `FetchData` that uses the `Virtualize` component.

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SO76117538.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <Virtualize ItemsProvider="ForecastService.GetForecastsAsync">
            <tr>
                <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@context.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@context.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        </Virtualize>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the `WeatherForecastProvider` which is my dummy data store.

```cs
namespace SO76117538.Data;

public class WeatherForecastProvider
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

    private List<WeatherForecast>? _forecasts;

    public async Task<IQueryable<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastAsync()
    {
        if (_forecasts is null)
             _forecasts = await this.LoadForecastAsync();

        return _forecasts.AsQueryable();
    }

   private Task<List<WeatherForecast>> LoadForecastAsync()
    {
        DateOnly startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(1, 5000).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        }).ToList());
    }
}
```

And the Service Registration:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastProvider>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<WeatherForecastListHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<WeatherForecastService>();
```

> Note: I've kept this "simple" with no interfaces to decouple and abstract the code domains.